# How to hide the next button on qualtrics until a text field is filled in with text?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, qualtrics

I have a survey with two questions on the page (one that is multiple choice) and one that is a text entry question.

I want to hide the next button until the text entry question has been filled out but I've only been able to hide the next button indefinitely and it seems to not reappear after the text field has been filled in.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{   
    this.hideNextButton();
    (function() {
        $('form > input').keyup(function() {
            var empty = false;
            $('form > input').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    empty = true;
                }
            });

            if (empty) {hideNextButton ()} else {showNextButton ()}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: update your post with corresponding HTML !

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and quick reply! I'm not sure how to get that information for you. I tried to open the survey and hit F12 to get into the elements of the page but there is alot of html there. Is there an easier way to show you the piece that is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors. It looks like you are trying to use jQuery instead of Prototypejs. Besides that, you need to restrict your input element search to the question and there is only one input field so you only need one function. Try this (edited to defer initial next button hide):

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {   
    function hideEl(element) {
        element.hide();
    }   
    var nb = $('NextButton');
    hideEl.defer(nb);
    $(this.questionId).down('.InputText').on('keyup', function(event) {
        if(this.value.length == 0) nb.hide();
        else nb.show();
    });
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thank you so much! I can't express how grateful I am for the help!

Comment: Hello T. Gibbons, I'm having an issue with people who are taking the survey for the first time. When they are first taking the survey it doesn't hide the next button for them however if we re-take the survey it seems to work perfectly. Is there any other way to do this function?

Comment: T Gibbons that fixed the problem we were having. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: Hello, Is there any other way to try to achieve this or any other setting that I can toy with in qualtrics? Unfortunately it seems that people are still able to skip this question because it seems to only be hiding the next button during re-takes and not when a person takes the survey for the first time. If i click in the field that it's checking the length for and hit backspace the next button disappears so it's almost as if it doesn't recognize that the field is blank when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Seems that there is a timing issue in jfe (retakes are SE)...the script runs before the next button is there, so it can't hide what it can't find. I've updated the code above...give it a try.

Comment: Thank you SOOO much T. Gibbons! That solved it perfectly and I can't express how grateful I am for all of your help =D